PIL Image Crop and Resize Degrading Quality
I am writing an image-processing script.

Hits background removal API
Detect item bounds in the image
Crops image based on bounds co-ordinates and places it on a 1400 x 1000 canvas
Save to PNG

The image I got back from the background removal API is the perfect colour and quality.

But once I crop, place on canvas and save, the colours are not as bright, and the quality is not as good.

Below is my crop and save function.
def crop_and_resize_sneaker(bg_removed_image_path, bounding_box, output_dir, image_name):
    """
    Crops and resizes an image to fit a 1400 x 1000 canvas while maintaining quality.
    Uses PIL to handle images with an emphasis on preserving the original quality,
    especially during resizing and saving operations.
    """
    try:
        # Load the image with background removed
        image = Image.open(bg_removed_image_path).convert('RGBA')

        # Extract bounding box coordinates
        x, y, w, h = bounding_box

        # Crop the image based on the bounding box
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, x + w, y + h))

        # Define output dimensions
        output_width, output_height = 1400, 1000

        # Calculate new dimensions to maintain aspect ratio
        aspect_ratio = w / h
        if aspect_ratio > (output_width / output_height):
            new_width = output_width
            new_height = int(output_width / aspect_ratio)
        else:
            new_width = int(output_height * aspect_ratio)
            new_height = output_height

        # Resize the image using LANCZOS (high-quality)
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.LANCZOS)

        # Create a new image for the final output with a transparent background
        final_image = Image.new('RGBA', (output_width, output_height), (0, 0, 0, 0))

        # Calculate center positioning
        start_x = (output_width - new_width) // 2
        start_y = (output_height - new_height) // 2

        # Paste the resized image onto the transparent canvas
        final_image.paste(resized_image, (start_x, start_y), resized_image)

        # Save the final image as PNG with maximum quality settings
        final_img_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'resized', f'{image_name}_sneaker_canvas.png')
        final_image.save(final_img_path, 'PNG', quality=95)  # Although 'quality' has no effect on PNGs, provided for completeness

        return final_img_path
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in cropping and resizing sneaker: {e}")
        return None

How can I ensure the crop and resize image is of equal quality as the input image (background removed)?

save_image() is not called anywhere. removing that, your issue doesn't even involve opencv anymore. -- use PIL's own ability to save images.

@ChristophRackwitz thanks for pointing that out, I edited the post. I am using PIL to save during  final_image.save(final_img_path, 'PNG', quality=95), but the quality is still worse than original

I isolated the exact step where the quality is reduced:
from: final_image = Image.new('RGBA', (output_width, output_height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
to: final_img_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'resized', f'{image_name}_sneaker_canvas.png')

Your "good" image has an attached colour profile. My money is on that profile getting lost somewhere along the way. There’s probably a way to transplant any profile from image to final_image, but don’t ask me how. =) (Edit: Ah, I see you got there already! :-) )

The issue was the original PNG had an embedded color profile and that profile was not being transferred when the new image was saved.
The below code solved the issue:
profile = resized_image.info.get("icc_profile", "")
final_image.save(final_img_path, format="PNG", icc_profile=profile)

